# Clangd.main out of memory while processing UE5 project

Tags: c++, qt-creator, unreal-engine5, clangd

Attempting to use QT creator as a C++ IDE for UE5 project on Linux. Engine built, and project generated all good. have the .pro file for QT creator. When opening it, it starts to parse the files. Takes a few minutes and then it just close…
Looking into the issue seems like when QT creator starts to parse, it generates a compiled_commands.json file. When that file reach about 19GB in size a new process started by QT (ClangD), that starts to consume all available RAM (32GB). When it runs out, it crashes (Both clangd.main and QT creator). - Task killed by OOM killer (out of memory)
Not sure why or how to fix.

Using Arch Linux (6.2.7-arch1-1 ), with QT Creator 9.0.2, ClangD 15.0.7
Project freshly generated by the editor no modification before opening it. (.pro project files generated after project by GenerateProjectFiles.sh -QMakefile)

Tried to reinstall clanged and qt creator - same result

Tried to build clangd from source - same result

Tried to run Qt from terminal to see if any error ( no error message, terminal also crash. If output redirected to a file, file remains empty)

Comment: a 19GB compile_commands file sounds like a lot. Does adding the `-CurrentPlatform` flag to GenerateProjectfiles.sh help a bit?

Comment: Adding -CurrentPlatform flag makes no difference, same result.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently creating a unreal-clangd extension. I use ubt to create the compile commands file though. This cc file is for intellisense only and only contains your project's files so wont have all unreal symbols.

The solution I came up with was to create a completionHelper.cpp. It's not part of your code. Currently in completionHelper.cpp I include "Engine.h", "Runtime/Engine/Public/EngineSharedPCH.h", and "Net/UnrealNetwork.h".

I include this completionHelper in my Intellisense compile commands file.

I also have a way to add all headers from a directory to completionHelper for any plugins that I need symbols for.

Another thing I found is that I have to open completionHelper.cpp at VSCode start and let clangd process it to also include any Unreal macros into code completion.

When processing completionHelper VSCode's memory can go to ~1.5GB. After, it will settle down to ~1GB.